# Exporting excel sheet to PDF - how to modify the font, spacing, size?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to export an excel sheet to pdf or word doc, it doesnt really matter. I know how to do that.

The real problem is : The Excel sheet in question is showing names of different employees. Under these names, we can see a list of every compagny they ever worked for. The name list is horizontaly long.

I want to be able to modify the format of the the sheet when the extraction happens.

Since there's a lot of names, i want to be able to modify the font, spacing, tie them up a little so everything can fit in one page.

Thank you !

```
Sub MakePDF()
'
' MakePDF Macro
'

'
    ChDir "C:\Users\charle\Desktop"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\charle\Desktop\EXCEL2PDF.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try something like `ActiveSheet.FitToPagesWide = 1` ?

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious where should i put this line?

Comment: Put it before `ChDir` line